# How to declare temponary/variable table with a dynamic number of column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table like this:

```
Table Name|Number of columns
```

How to dynamically create temporary tables inside stored procedure with names from first table, and variable columns named e.g. col1, col2, etc..
I also need to insert values to them and make another logic on them.

Example:

```
Table1|3

Table1(col1 nvarchar(max), col2 nvarchar(max), col3 nvarchar(max))
```

Comment: Where possible, recast your solution across *rows* rather than *columns*. Tables are not spreadsheets. Tables are expected to have a fixed set of columns and a variable number of rows. Leave any final pivoting to whatever front-end or report builder is *consuming* the results.

Comment: Don't. This will be extremely painful. Generating the statements to build these tables is painful, generating the code to consume them is painful, and forget about any debugging assistance, because there isn't any. Pick any language other than T-SQL to do it in and you'll probably have a much better time. This does mean writing it as client code or an ETL package and not as a stored procedure -- if having it as a stored procedure is an absolute requirement, you can use service broker to communicate with the client app. Alternatively, and depending on your use case -- consider Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use dynamic sql like below:

```
declare @counter int = 1
declare @numberOfCols int = 3 -- OR you can use ->(select numberofcolumns from firsttable)
declare @dynamic nvarchar(max) = ''
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'CREATE TABLE #TEMP (';

while @counter <= @numberofCols
begin
   set @dynamic = @dynamic + 'col'+cast(@counter as nvarchar(5))+' nvarchar(max) ';   
   if(@counter <> @numberOfCols)
   begin
      set @dynamic = @dynamic + ', ';
   end 
   set @counter = @counter + 1
end

set @sql = @sql + @dynamic + ') select * from #temp'
select @sql

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a stored procedure regarding your question. I wish it can help you.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE P_ProcedureName
    @NumberOfColumns    INT=2 --expected 1 or more column

AS

DECLARE @SQLString  VARCHAR(MAX)=''
DECLARE @Seq        INT=2

IF @NumberOfColumns=0 
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Please add valid number of column'
    RETURN
END

CREATE TABLE #Table
(
     Id INT NOT NULL    IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,Column1            VARCHAR(MAX)
)


WHILE @Seq<=@NumberOfColumns
BEGIN
    SET @SQLString=@SQLString+'ALTER TABLE #Table ADD Column'+CAST(@Seq AS VARCHAR)+' VARCHAR(MAX)'+char(13)
    PRINT(@SQLString)
    SET @Seq +=1
END
EXEC(@SQLString)

SELECT * FROM #Table

GO


P_ProcedureName 5
```